# Error 502 while inserting into my SQL database, no primary key

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax

I am working on a dashboard for my team, that allows to get information on our projects. When creating a new project in the dashboard, the user must fill a form with the name, starting date and closing date of the project. However, I have an issue when inserting a project that has a name already existing in database, and I am not able to find a solution as each project has its own index (with an auto-incremented integer column in DB), and the project name column is not a primary key of the table. It works perfectly when using a different name, for example if "project summer" is in DB, inserting "project summer" will fail (leading to an error 502) but "project summer 2" will not. How can I insert new projects with similar names?

I am using NodeJS with express, ajax and request, and my database uses mySQL managed with PHPMyAdmin.

EDIT (03/12/2018): "Name" column appears to be a table index. What can be the consequences on the table if I edit the column to not act as an index anymore?

[image: Table structure]

Comment: check the index is unique or not. If it is unique it will not allow duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a snip of your schema ? Without looking at your code it might be tough to see what your mappings are

Edit:  I think “key” and “index” in MySQL mean the same thing.  You can only have have 1 primary key  and it looks like you have one above.  Try and remove the index from the name table

Comment: Hi, just edited the post, Name column is an index but not a primary key..

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL Reserved Words.** There are reserved words in MySQL which cannot be used as identifiers (**table or column names etc**.) without being quoted with **backticks (`)**. Quoting of identifiers was introduced in **MySQL Version 3.23.6**. You can also enclose identifiers with **double quotation marks (")** if you run MySQL in **ANSI** mode.

You can use it like :

```
Insert into `tablename` (`name`) VALUES ("xyz");
```